How to create an airgapped installation of Appsmith for personal use?
I want to create an airgapped installation of Appsmith for my personal use.
I plan to download the community version from GitHub and modify the code accordingly.
However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to perform a local and personal open-source installation in an airgapped environment. Has anyone successfully achieved this before and can provide guidance or suggestions?
I appreciate any help. Thank you!
